# How To Create Cross Browser Asp.net Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, cross-browser, custom-controls

I'm goingto create an asp.net control which should be cross browser. and support some skin - multilanguage and rtl & ltr support.
I want to know what should I consider and also looking for a good article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this series: [**Building ASP.NET User and Server Contro**](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020319.htm)ls

Answer (score 1):

Write valid xhtml.

Read this article on [How to make Cross Browser Websites](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/crossbrowser.html). It doesn't really have to do with if you use asp.net or php to create re-usable web-controls / sites. You just need to follow the standards and maybe apply some hacks if you want to support older versions of web-browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser designs generally depends on what kinda design features you want to support, best thing to get started with is learning [asp.net control adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/), It's basically bunch of ready made samples that shows how to detect browser early in the execution of the request and reflect to the design using in-built actions provided by asp.net technology, or write your own!

Hope this helps